# Yii2: how to stop css compression

Tags: yii2, yui-compressor

i don't want to compress my `css` and `js` files. Is there any way to do it.?
i have tried making `css` compressor false but still cant do it. 
P.S `css` and `js` files ain't compressed while the site is on my local but as soon as i make on live on `AWS` then it compresses them.

Comment: By default Yii2 does not do anything with the CSS files. So the fact that it does that with you means that it is configured like that. You should take a look at the configuration of the `assetManager` and your various `AssetBundle classes.`

Comment: can you please tell me where is this configuration file located..?